# TouchableOpacity.onPress event is not fired

Tags: react-native

I have 2 texts which i want to navigate to different pages with but i need an image in between them...but the text thats above the image (in this case "wc collar") does not navigate and is not clickable but when i remove the image it works...i even tried removing the touchable opacity and just adding the onpress to the text but it still produces the same result

```
<View>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Collar')}
        style={{ width: 90, height: 40 }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textstyle}> WC COLLAR</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Circlet')}
        style={{ width: 90, height: 40 }}
      >
        <Text style={styles.textstyle2}> WC CIRCLET</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Image
      source={require('../images/portlog.png')}
      style={{ width: 1366, height: 650, position: 'absolute', top: 200 }}
    />
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
  </View>
</View>
```

Comment: The **Absolutely positioned Image** you're having is over your `TouchableOpacity` component ... preventing the onPress event to fire

Comment: @HendElSahili thanks...i tried moving it out of the way and now it works